# How to uninstall Android upgrade

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, performance, downgrade

I was asked by my Galaxy Grand to update. It was a 608 MB build update. After done , now I got Android Jelly-bean 4.2.2 . It is making my phone very slow and uses too much phone memory. Want to uninstall, How can I do it without resetting device ???

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Android, especially on Samsung devices, is generally not possible because Samsung includes bootloaders in OTAs that prohibit installing older Android versions than the one the bootloader was meant to run.

I think you can use Odin to do a *reflash* of Android 4.1, but I think you'd lose some data with that.